# NectarJS goes wrong

Tags: gcc, nectarjs

I  did `necater   --verbose   a.js`
and  I  run
`./a*.bin`

Here  is  the  result:

```
i
./a-linux-x86-64.bin: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./a-linux-x86-64.bin)
./a-linux-x86-64.bin: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./a-linux-x86-64.bin)
```

Comment: Did you type `necater` or is it typo in question and it had to be `nectar`?

Comment: it's  no  need  to  have  to  be  necterjs,anyway  to  fix  it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have glibc++ to execute the compiled program.

Now, NectarJS has been updated and is able to compile locally, therefore, you can try it again.